# Format results from a Get-WmiObject script to match list from get-content .txt file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that will get drive current drive space on our servers and return them to an output file.

Here is the script as of now:

```
    $ServerName = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Testing Files\serverlist.txt"
    Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ServerName -Filter DriveType=3 | Select-Object DeviceID, @{'Name'='Size (GB)'; 'Expression'={Expression'={[string]::Format('{0:NO}',[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB))}}, @{'Name'='Freespace (GB)'; 'Expression'={[string]::Format('{0:NO}',[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB))}}
    
    Out-file "C:\users\xxxxxx\desktop\testing files\server space results.txt"
```

will not write to a text file; only displays results

The results display device ID, size (GB), freespace (GB) with no issues except one.  Every drive is listed as C: and E: but does not split them up based on the device name so it is hard to tell which results go to which server.  Below is a sample of the results of the script:

```
DeviceID Size (GB) Freespace (GB)
-------- --------- --------------
C:       58        13
E:       499       499
C:       79        30
E:       799       103
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all - the formatting in your question is a complete mess and hard to read. I did notice this though so, what's going on with this bit `@{'Name'='Size (GB)'; 'Expression'={Expression'={[string]`?

Comment: @notjustme I changed the initial question.  Let me know if that makes more sense.  I got the initial script from a co-worker and tried to modify it to fit what I needed to do.  I am still learning powershell scripting so getting explanations from users that know more than I helps me to understand what certain things do.

Comment: No, I had no problem with the title of the question. The problem is with the code formatting... I'll add a code block for you, but that'll only do so much.

Comment: Oh shoot.  Well thats what i get from not getting enough sleep last night lol.  Let me see if I can format it to look the way it should.

Comment: Yeah, I still can't make any sense of this bit though `'Expression'={Expression'={[string]::Format('{0:NO}'`. Maybe it's me who is in need of sleep, I dunno...

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to how I could get the following?

Using a list of servers, get an output of the following:
Server Name, Drive Letter, Total Drive Size, Available Drive Space

I feel like there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: You're completely ignoring what I'm telling you about this bit `'Expression'={Expression'={`...

Comment: There were a few things going on here.  He also had an "O" instead of a zero in `'{0:N0}'`... Check my answer it has the corrections and tested good.

Comment: Sorry, my page didnt update so I missed your answer.  Ill give that a shot and let you know.

Comment: It is a thing of beauty.  I didnt even realize that I had typed 'O' instead of '0'.  The addition of PSComputerName formatted it perfectly.

My output .txt file is coming out blank though.  is there a switch I need to add to the end?

Comment: I'm not sure why you aren't getting the data in the file.  Make sure you correct for the path, as I think both of us were playing around to test etc...  I updated the answer with a slightly cleaner version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few typos and/or syntax errors.  Also if you want the Computer Name PowerShell adds the PSComputerName property:

```
$ServerName = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Testing Files\serverlist.txt"
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ServerName -Filter DriveType=3 | 
Select-Object PSComputerName,DeviceID, 
    @{'Name'='Size (GB)'; Expression = {[string]::Format('{0:N0}',[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB))}}, 
    @{'Name'='Freespace (GB)'; Expression = {[string]::Format('{0:N0}',[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB))}} |
Out-file "C:\users\xxxxxx\desktop\testing files\server space results.txt"
```

Note: I prefer to use win32_Volume instead.  Also you should think about using `Get-CimInstance` instead of `Get-WMIObject`.  The latter is deprecated.

### Update

Here's a slightly modified version.  I typically use `[Math]::Round()` in these cases.  It will keep the value numeric so it aligns right.

```
$ServerName = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Testing Files\serverlist.txt"
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ServerName -Filter DriveType=3 | 
Select-Object PSComputerName,DeviceID, 
    @{'Name'='Size (GB)'; Expression = { [Math]::Round( ($_.size / 1GB), 0 ) } }, 
    @{'Name'='Freespace (GB)'; Expression = { [Math]::Round( ($_.freespace / 1GB), 0 ) } } |
Out-file "C:\temp\xxxxxx\desktop\testing files\server space results.txt"
```

Comment: Script works great but still cant seem to get any information in the output text file.  I may try to output to a .csv instead.

Comment: Finally got it.  Not sure what the issue was but it finally wrote to a .txt file in the correct format.  Thanks for your help!